# Get the data from the subscribed topic at Cloudmqtt in JS to Alexa Skill

Tags: javascript, mqtt, alexa-skills-kit

I am currently try to get the data from cloudmqtt by subscribe to a topic. But when I try to convert it to string so that my Alexa could read it the test service of Alexa tell me "The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid."

My Subscribing code is as follow

```
    var mqtt = require('mqtt');

function DHTSensorInSession(intent, session, callback) {
    const cardTitle = intent.name;
    let repromptText = '';
    let sessionAttributes = {};
    const shouldEndSession = true;
    let speechOutput = '';
    let Tempe = '';
        var mqttpromise = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
            var client = mqtt.connect({port:19546,host:'m14.cloudmqtt.com',username:'jkgnbggq',password:'VbG2-RvZTEt-'})

            client.on('connect', function() { // When connected
                // publish a message to any mqtt topic
                client.publish('main/light/esp', 'connected')
                client.subscribe('main/sensor/temp')
            });
            client.on('message',function(topic,message){
                if(topic.toString() === 'main/sensor/temp')
                {
                    Tempe += message.toString();
                }
                client.end();
                resolve('Done sending');

            })

        });
        mqttpromise.then(
            function(data) {
                console.log('Function called succesfully:', data);
                sessionAttributes = createSensorAttributes(Tempe);
                speechOutput = "That wire less light has been turned " + Tempe;
                repromptText = "Ok, turning the light " + Tempe;
                callback(sessionAttributes,buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
            },
            function(err) {
                console.log('An error occurred:', err);
            }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the logs for your lambda to locate any error messages. These can be found in the AWS console, or using the ASK CLI command "ask lambda log ...".

These may appear a bit cryptic at first, but they can be very helpful when something goes wrong. Look for the entries with the words "error" or "fail". Often they will include a line number of your index.js (or other) file showing you exactly which line is causing the problem.

Alternatively, create unit tests to test your code locally before uploading.

There are lots of articles and posts online about doing this.

Comment: Yeah I fix the code and it run, but another problem appeared, I can't get the data from the subscribed topic (cloudmqtt), I think it is due to when I connect to the subscribed topic, the message is no longer there, but I have not figured out how to fix it yet

Answer (score 0):

MQTT doesn't work that way.

Normally messages are only delivered to already connected clients that are subscribed to a topic at the instant they the message is published. The exception to this is if the message is flagged as retained, in this case the LAST message published will be delivered to a new client at the point where they subscribe to the topic.

Comment: so whenever the code run it will waiting for a new message to process right?
So I think that is the reason why my Lambda function didn't get anything from the Cloudmqtt topic and my assigned variable appeared to be blank.
Do you have any idea so that the Lambda function will wait until there is some message appear in the topic and then end the client session. Thank you very much